# Can I access __DATA__ section in mac os x automator

Tags: perl, automator

I am trying to use the `__DATA__` section in a perl script that's run inside automator.

When run as a shell script everything's fine, but inside automator the data section looks like it's empty.

Any idea as to why, and a better workaround than having a gigantic "here" file?

## EDIT

example script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<DATA>){
    print $_;
}
__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: Can you give a working sample?

Comment: Not really understand the close votes. This is an valid question. Vote to close, only because someone knows nothing about the Automator is pity. Anyway, editing the question - and adding an example.

Comment: perl does the equivalent of `open DATA, '<', $0` and `seek DATA, $data_start, 0` when your program starts. I have no idea what *Automator* has done to this, but you could try writing `seek DATA, 0, 0; print while <DATA>;` and see if you get your source code output. It's also worth adding `CHECK {print tell(DATA), "\n"; }` and checking whether the output is the same with and without Automator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Automator.app` runs your script as

```
/usr/bin/perl -e 'your script here' --
```

therefore the `__DATA__` handle doesn't works.

---

**EDIT** how to determined

- the Automator.app runs by definition `/usr/bin/perl`, so:
- renamed the `/usr/bin/perl` to `/usr/bin/perl_ORIG`
- added another perl script in its place (other perl), + `chmod 755`

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = 0;
print "$0\n";
for my $arg (@ARGV) {
        print "$n:[$arg]\n";
        $n++;
}
```

- runs the original script in the Automator
- on the output the fake "perl" shows exactly all arguments up to `--`

Not very nice (nor correct) - but helped to discover how the Automator runs the scripts, e.g. it uses the `-e` (lowercase), `script content` + `--`.

Also, the `tell DATA` returns `0` in the Automator, in the normal script it return the real position in the file. (see Borodin's comment)

Comment: Nice sleuthing - how did you determine that?

Comment: @MarkSetchell used not very correct method, (see the edit) but helped... :)